# Unable to read new keys from App.config in C#.NET Windows Application

Tags: c#, app-config

my app.config file has 6 key-value pairs.

- I earlier had only three of them.
- I ran the application many a times before adding 3 more keys
  recently.
- But doing this, I always get "Null object reference" error.
- I can still read the old 3 values using below code, but it is unable
  to return me the values of newly added 3 keys:

```
return 
  System.Configuration
    .ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FTPDirectory").ToString();
```

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: could you share your app.config file or just the key/values

Comment: This should be pretty straight forward. You posted no code, so it's hard to say why you're "...unable to read" stuff.

Comment: close Visual studio and restart the app...it may work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you recompiling between changes to the app.config?  msbuild will copy your app.config to the output folder as .exe.config, for example.